# Asp.net Identity class connectivity with oracle 11g via Entity framework 6

Tags: oracle11g, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-6.1

I've to use Oracle 11g with ASP.NET MVC 5 and Entity Framework 6. I'm trying to use ASP.NET Identity for user authentication and role management and i want asp.net identity class to use my user table stored in my Oracle 11g DB. I am using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and ODP.NET in my project. What is the best way to configure Identity with Oracle using EF6 in MVC 5 project? Is it even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think ultimately you are going to need a provider for Oracle.  A quick google search revealed this one:

https://github.com/timmkrause/AspNet.Identity.OracleProvider

Another suggestion per my comment to look into

http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/

Or as previously stated you implement the identity interfaces yourself for your own implementation.

Comment: Thanks Shawn for your reply but this is a pre-release unstable version so i can't rely on this plus there is no documentation available about this library.

Comment: Understood, it was just an example I don't know if there are any stable releases honestly.  I have found the EF support on Oracle databases very lacking.  That being said, I believe you would have to write your own Identity provider should one not be available to use that meets your needs.  Again on a quick browse: http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/ and it looks like there is good documentation if you do some digging around the Oracle area.